# iOS Crash GameObject::IsActive() const

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

I found XCode Organizer Crash Report many crashes.The Top is Following:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000156
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ios                             0x000000010107e9bc GameObject::IsActive() const + 16 (GameObject.cpp:425)
1   ios                             0x00000001013bb168 UI::CanvasManager::AddDirtyRenderer(UI::Canvas*, UI::CanvasRenderer*) + 36 (GameObject.h:575)
2   ios                             0x00000001013bba08 UI::CanvasRenderer::SetMesh(Mesh*) + 440 (CanvasRenderer.cpp:572)
3   ios                             0x000000010142b32c CanvasRenderer_CUSTOM_SetMesh(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*) + 68 (CanvasRendererBindings.gen.cpp:296)
4   ios                             0x0000000100b515cc Graphic_DoMeshGeneration_m2913299565 + 988 (Bulk_UnityEngine.UI_0.cpp:27200)
5   ios                             0x0000000100b50c98 Graphic_Rebuild_m2617722358 + 92 (GeneratedVirtualInvokers.h:25)
6   ios                             0x0000000100b458bc CanvasUpdateRegistry_PerformUpdate_m2200492017 + 904 (Bulk_UnityEngine.UI_0.cpp:18024)
7   ios                             0x0000000100f02854 RuntimeInvoker_Void_t1841601450(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) + 28 (Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp:3647)
8   ios                             0x0000000101962460 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**) + 68 (Runtime.cpp:497)
9   ios                             0x0000000101358bc8 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExc... + 100 (ScriptingApi_Il2Cpp.cpp:213)
10  ios                             0x00000001013516e0 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool) + 60 (ScriptingInvocation.cpp:303)
11  ios                             0x00000001013bb45c UI::CanvasManager::WillRenderCanvases() + 60 (ScriptingInvocation.h:71)
12  ios                             0x0000000101253010 PlayerLoop() + 1036 (PlayerLoop.cpp:197)
13  ios                             0x00000001014cfc54 UnityPlayerLoopImpl(bool) + 32 (LibEntryPoint.mm:221)
14  ios                             0x000000010008268c UnityRepaint + 140 (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:268)
15  ios                             0x0000000100082578 -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] + 88 (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:77)
16  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a222f24 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch(unsigned long long) + 44 (CADisplay.mm:1899)
17  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a222dd0 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 444 (CADisplay.mm:1334)
18  IOKit                           0x000000018723a094 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372 (IOKitLib.c:1190)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f62e50 __CFMachPortPerform + 180 (CFMachPort.c:682)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f7b218 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56 (CFRunLoop.c:1959)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f7a9cc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:2078)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186f784b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1840 (CFRunLoop.c:3028)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186ea62b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
24  GraphicsServices                0x000000018895a198 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
25  UIKit                           0x000000018ceed7fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684 (UIApplication.m:2650)
26  UIKit                           0x000000018cee8534 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4092)
27  ios                             0x000000010007c690 main + 160 (main.mm:33)
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185e895b8 start + 4
```

I search for a few days but have no idea.

Environment:

- **Unity 5.6.4p1**
- **Xcode 11.3**
- **il2cpp**

Devices:

- **iPhone 6**
- **iPhone 6s**
- **iPhone 6p**
- **iPhone 7**
- **iPad 5**
- **iPad 6**
- **also a little parts on iPhone XS、XS Max**

iOS version:

- **9-13.x**

I can't reproduce on local device, so can't confirm wether it's fixed.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug (**[DISABLING UI CRASHES AT GAMEOBJECT::ISACTIVE](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/disabling-ui-crashes-at-gameobject-isactive)**), try to upgrade Unity to the latest stable version.